# How to define a polynomial with abstract coefficients in Sage

Tags: math-software, sagemath

Let $f=ax^2+b$ be a polynomial in $Q[x]$, how to define $f$ in sage?

Answer (score 2):

```
sage: var('a b')
(a, b)
sage: R.<X> = QQ[]
sage: f = a * X * X + b
sage: f
X^2*a + b
sage: R 
Univariate Polynomial Ring in X over Rational Field
```

You can get more information about polynomials [in this tutorial here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_polynomial.html).